# Transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a chapter exercise from Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra (fourth edition).

In what range of $a$ and $b$ is the following equation a Markov process?

$u_{k+1} = Au_k = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 1-a & 1-b\end{pmatrix}u_k \quad $ and $ \quad u_0 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

---

I believe what the problem is asking is for the values of $a$ and $b$  so that the matrix is a transition probability matrix. The eigenvalues of a transition matrix must (?) contain $\lambda_1 = 1$. Hence, I am only left with one last eigenvalue. Since the sum of the main diagonal is $a-b+1$, hence, $\lambda_2 = a-b$.

For this to be a stable matrix, (powers of $A$ not blow up), then $|a-b|\leq1$. Is this thinking correct?

Thanks

Comment: If you just want your matrix to be a transition probability matrix, then you just want to ensure all entries are nonnegative and the sum of each column is equal to $1$, *i.e.*, $\mathbf{A}$ should be left stochastic. So $a,b \in [0, 1]$. Unless you need your Markov process to have additional properties.

Comment: I think the text requires an additional property on the eigenvalues as I have stated above. I was confused reading this problem, since I also know that the columns should add to 1. In this problem, they certainly do, and I felt it is almost trivial. I'm sure I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

To be a probability transition matrix where the state is a column vector, the matrix needs to be right stochastic, which means the column sums are equal to 1, and the entries have to be nonnegative. Here the column sums are automatically $1$ by the construction, so you merely need nonnegativity, that is, you need $a \geq 0,1-a \geq 0,b \geq 0,1-b \geq 0$. This means you need $a,b \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Is it not true that the way the question is written that the matrix would need to be *left* stochastic, *i.e.* sum of columns equal to $1$? The state is described by a column vector.

Comment: @megas You're right, I'm poorly accustomed to this convention. Let me fix it.